# Изменить заголовок для API в redoc и swagger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

Настраиваю отображение в redoc и swagger, operation_id я изменяю, они меняются, как видно на скриншоте, мне нужно поменять название "events" на "Мероприятия". использую библиотеку drf-yasg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В swagger_auto_schema нужно прописать tags=["Название"]